# Writing bytes to java socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to write 0x87 in a Java socket I've created.

```
tcpSocket = new Socket(server, port);
tcpWriteToServer = new PrintWriter(tcpSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
byte [] header = {0x8, 0x7};
tcpWriteToServer.print(header);
```

On the server side I get:

```
Incoming Bytes: 0x5b 0x42 0x40 0x34 0x32 0x65 0x62 0x35 0x62 0x38 0x38
```

I tried to break down the problem and just send one byte:

```
tcpWriteToServer.print(header[0]);
```

For this I end up getting:

```
Incoming Bytes: 0x38
```

I'm not sure how that "3" in "0x38" gets read. I read "0x37" when I try to send "0x7".

The server side is written in python and I have no issues sending the bytes and reading correctly in python.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: read the doc for `PrintWriter`. It does not do what you think it does. Also there is no `print(byte[])` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea what I might be missing?

You have to decide whether you want to write text or binary.  Combining them is likely to be a good way to confuse yourself.

I suggest you use binary in this case.

```
tcpSocket = new Socket(server, port);
out = tcpSocket.getOutputStream();
out.write(0x8);
out.write(0x7);
```

You can also buffer the output like this.

```
out = new BufferedOutputStream(tcpSocket.getOutputStream());
out.write(0x8);
out.write(0x7);
out.flush();
```

If you have an array of bytes you can write them in one go.

```
byte[] header = { .... };
out.write(header);
```

> I'm not sure how that "3" in "0x38" gets read. I read "0x37" when I try to send "0x7".

There is no `print(byte)` but there is a `print(int)` so when you do

```
print(8);
```

it is the same as

```
print(Integer.toString(8));
```

or

```
print("8");
```

or

```
print('8')
```

and '8' = 0x38 in ASCII

Answer (score 1):

> Incoming Bytes: 0x5b 0x42 0x40 0x34 0x32 0x65 0x62 0x35 0x62 0x38 0x38

If you print out character representation of each of this bytes

```
byte[] bytes = {0x5b, 0x42, 0x40, 0x34, 0x32, 0x65, 0x62, 0x35, 0x62, 0x38, 0x38};
for (byte b : bytes){
    System.out.print((char)b);
}
```

you will see that your code sends `[B@42eb5b88`.

It happens because since PrintWriter has no `print(byte[])` method it uses `print(Object obj)` which just sends String representation of object `obj`. Such string is created with `String.valueOf(obj)` which internally is using `obj.toString()` method, which for arrays returns `typeName` (`[b` - one dimensional `[` array of bytes `b`), `@` and `hexHashCode`.

In other words you didn't send content of `header` array, but result of its `toString()` method.

If you want to send bytes it is easier to use `Stream` (Writers ware meant to handle text, not bytes) and their `write(byte[])` method. If you want to be also able to send text instead of bytes you can use `PrintStream`

```
PrintStream tcpWriteToServer = new PrintStream(tcpSocket.getOutputStream(), true);    
tcpWriteToServer.write(header);
```